# Работа с камерой в OpenGL.

Tags: sdl, golang, opengl

Разбираюсь с OpenGL. Использую OpenGL + SDL на Go, но наверное это не так важно, похоже у меня ошибка именно в вызовах OpenGL API.

Пытаюсь поработать с камерой, но не могу ничего увидеть, лишь чёрный экран.

Сперва я настраиваю проекцию:

```
gl.Viewport(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight)
gl.MatrixMode(gl.PROJECTION)
gl.LoadIdentity()
glu.Perspective(45, screenWidth/screenHeight, 0.1, 100)
```

После этого устанавливаю камеру:

```
gl.MatrixMode(gl.MODELVIEW)
gl.LoadIdentity()
glu.LookAt(
  10, 10, 5,
  0, 0, 0,
  -1, -1, 1)
```

После этого пытаюсь нарисовать следующее:

```
gl.Clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

gl.Color4f(1, 1, 1, 1)
gl.Begin(gl.QUADS)

gl.Vertex3d(-20, 20, 0)
gl.Vertex3d(20, 20, 0)
gl.Vertex3d(20, -20, 0)
gl.Vertex3d(-20, -20, 0)

gl.End()
```

Но вижу только чёрный экран. Скорее всего я как-то не так настраиваю камеру/проекцию. Если вдруг ошибка где-то в другом месте **[здесь полный код](https://gist.github.com/3605519)**.

Comment: @Vladimir VG Ради интереса, как в итоге решилась проблема?

Comment: никак не решилась, я взял чужой работающий пример и начал его под себя модифицировать. Там была проблема в какой-то не известной для меня детали.

Answer (score 1):

С ходу без компилятора сложно дебагнуть. Тут скорее всего порядок вызовов неправильный в каком-то месте. Попробуйте также вместо прямоугольника нарисовать два треугольника.

Идея:

```
//Было:
gl.Begin(gl.QUADS)
//Стало
gl.Begin(gl.GL_QUADS)
//И так со всеми константами. Странно что они без перфикса в имени. 
//Хотя наверное это особенность реализации OpenGL на Go и это неверно.
```

Еще одна идея:

```
gl.Color4f(1, 1, 1, 1)
//Прозрачный белый цвет накладывается на то что уже есть в frambuffeе, а там по умолчанию черный прямоуголньик, поэтому вам и выдает пустой экран. Поробуйте что-нибудь вроде.
gl.Color4f(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
//Здесь я тоже ошибся  1 = непрозрачность. Так что эта строка правильная.
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вместо `glu.LookAt()` использовать следующую функцию:

```
glTranslatef(0,0,-3);
glRotatef (-45, 1.0, 0.0 , 0.0);
glRotatef (0, 1.0, 0.0 , 0.0);
glRotatef (-90, 0.0, 0.0 , 1.0);
```

Кажется координаты тут неправильные, попробуйте осмотреться вокруг меняя значения

Comment: неа, не помогло. Немного поигрался с коэффициентами -- тоже ничего.

Comment: У меня нормально показывает твой код. Дельфи 7. А ты `SwapBuffers(DC);` делаешь после отрисовки?

Comment: Да, по ссылке лежит полный код, там есть SwapBuffers. Спасибо за инфу, буду дальше думать.